# Will we have enough time to make our connecting flight at Heathrow?

Tags: transit, lhr, short-connections, british-airways

We will arrive at London Heathrow at 7:05 am in Terminal 5 from Brussels. Our next flight will be at 8:30 am, also in Terminal 5. We have stopover of 1 hour 25 minutes, and we must be at our departure gate no later than 20 minutes before the departure time, giving use just about 1 hour to make the transfer time.

Is this enough time to make this connecting flight? What would happen if the first flight is delayed or it is busy going through Customs?

I've heard that it takes some time to go between Terminals 5a, 5b or 5c. How can I make this transfer as smooth as possible? Both flights are on British Airways and are booked as a single ticket.

Comment: Are they booked on a single ticket as connecting flights, or on two tickets?  If on two tickets, this is very dangerous.  If on a single ticket, it's still a little on the tight side, but at least British Airways would be responsible to help you out if you missed your second flight.

Answer (score 1):

They were booked as a single ticket which means BA thinks you have enough time to transfer. Also BA will be responsible for your onward travel if your first flight is late.